# Error installing vsftpd from Internet repository on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have an Ubuntu server. I am trying to install Vsftpd but it shows this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package vsftpd
```

After that, I checked the Internet connection by ping 4.2.2.4, which worked fine.

I tried to apt-get update but it was not possible it shows:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release.gpg
Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can ping 4.2.2.4, but can't ping us.archive.ubuntu.com it can be a problem with dns server. Try to ping us.archive.ubuntu.com.

Comment: I find out that my server can ping by IP address but cant ping by domain. For example I can`t ping www.google.com but I can ping 74.125.113.105

Comment: I went to /etc/apt/sources.list and changed all "us.archive.ubuntu.com" to  91.189.92.169 and apt-get update worked.

Answer (score 0):

As root, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, replacing `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com` with another [mirror](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).  Run `apt-get update` to fetch the new mirror's package list, then `apt-get install vsftpd`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's something wrong with your DNS setup.  Have a look in /etc/resolv.conf.  There should be one or more lines in there that look like this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

If there are no `nameserver` lines, then add those two.  They are provided by Google and are free to use.

If there *are* `nameserver` lines, test that they are working.

You can test if DNS is working with the `dig` tool.  Use `dig us.archive.ubuntu.com` to test your current setup.  use `dig @8.8.8.8 us.archive.ubuntu.com` to test a particular name server.